# How to connect to MSSQL in PHP using sqlsrv api?

Tags: php

I am trying to connect to MSSQL in PHP using sqlsrv api. When I run **phpinfo()**, it shows an a section for **sqlsrv**. But while actually writing code, I cannot connect to MSSQL. I am using SQL Server R2. I connect to the database from the Management Studio using the specified hostname. Here is the code:

```
<?php
        $serverName = "TEST-PC\SQLEXPRESS";
        $databaseName = "TestDB";

        $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"$databaseName");
        $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
        if( $conn === false ){
            echo "Could not connect.\n";
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
        else{
            echo "Connection created";
        }
        $tsql = "SELECT * FROM Test";
        $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);
        echo "Rows returned: ".sqlsrv_num_rows($result);
        sqlsrv_close();
    ?>
```

The code prints NOTHING on the page, not even any error message. Here is the entries in php.ini file:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll
```

Any help please?

Comment: Sorry, forgot mentioning that I am running the site on IIS 7 and NOT on Apache.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not pass a user or password, the driver is trying to connect via Windows Authentication. By running PHP from IIS, it will connect with the credentials of what whatever user IIS is running under (such as NT AUTHORITY\IUSR). You need to add the IIS user to the list of allowed logins to SQL Server, and then add a user associated with that login to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to put "$connectionOptions" where you have "$connectionOptions"?

[Turn on error_reporting for php for more verbose output.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

[EDIT]

A few possibile solutions:

1. Check your Connection String properties for the MSSQL Database you're connecting to (i.e. are you matching the values exactly, or can you use (local)
2. It's possible the User you're logged in on doesn't have proper access to the database. That sounds like an oversimplification, but check out your IIS settings, as well as FastCGI.impersonate settings. Turn on IIS Windows Authentication settings in IIS, and fastcgi.impersonate = 1. There's a thorough article about this potential issue here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/02/10/sql-server-driver-for-php-understanding-windows-authentication.aspx

Comment: Sorry........misprinted **HERE**. It's $connectionInfo, NOT $connectionOptions in actual code.

Comment: Can you connect to your database locally, does it use Windows Authentication or a Username / Password? If the latter, then you need to include that in your $connectionInfo

Comment: Also, make sure your SQL server is running

Comment: Yes, it uses Windows Authentication.

Comment: @ Dominic Tancredi : SQL Server is running. I use MSSQL for .NET applications. No problems with that.

Answer (score 0):

It is because sqlsrv_query() uses SQLSRV_CURSOR_FORWARD cursor type by default. However, in order to get a result from sqlsrv_num_rows(), you should choose one of these cursor types below:

SQLSRV_CURSOR_STATIC
SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET
SQLSRV_CURSOR_CLIENT_BUFFERED

For more information, check: [Cursor Types (SQLSRV Driver)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh487160(v=sql.105).aspx)

In conclusion, Try this Code:

`$tsql=sqlsrv_query("SELECT * FROM Test");
 $row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows($tsql);
 echo $row_count;`